# CPT Metabox with email notification

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, email

I have a custom post type just for contacts, I want to create a metabox with the contacts birthday and have it notify the site admin when it comes up (Or a day/week/month before the date if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP doesn't have a *real* Cron Job System/APi, but it got the *Schedule API*, as you can see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/cron_schedules). Other related functions can be found [here in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) filed under "*See Also*". That's the closest you will get with WP.

Comment: Thanks Kaiser, I'll take a look, though I'm not sure how I would add this to a metabox.

Comment: `save_post` filter? Could you please mark the Q as answered. Thanks.